# Not able to get code from WSDL for Soap Service using wsdl2Objc (IPhone)

Tags: iphone, ios, soap, wsdl

I passed a URL (`https://amstest.aia.org/netforumaiatest2/xweb/secure/netforumxml.asmx`) and name of target folder to [wsdl2objc](http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/wiki/UsageInstructions) to generate the code to call a SOAP service, but I am not getting any generated .h/.m file in target folder. Does anyone know why?

(I am developing an iPhone app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've written several tutorials on wsdl2objc: they might help get you started.   http://brismith66.blogspot.com/search/label/iPhone%20Development

Answer (score 0):

I uesd the [sudzC](http://sudzc.com/)(online tool) for generating code and it is working fine for me (after correcting some errors in generated code).